# Slice array and concat in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In case  when `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]` all works great.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function range(min, max) {
    var startArr = arr.slice(arr.indexOf(min)),
        endArr = max < arr.length ? arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(max) + 1) : [];
    return startArr.concat(endArr);
}


range(3,1);
```

But in case when `arr = [{id:1, name: "John"}, {id:2, name: "Mark"}, {id:3, name: "Jim"},{id:4, name: "Bob"}]` this code not works.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgvjaghz/)

Comment: "this code not works" - How does it not work? Also you need strings for your names `John => "John"`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I added demo, it shows alway last item from array.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are expecting something like `{id:3, name: "Jim"},{id:4, name: "Bob"},{id:1, name: "John"}`. The reason why that's not happening is because `indexOf(min)` is getting index based on the direct value in the first array. In the array of objects it's not that simple, you will need to utilize `id` in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the `indexOf()` part of your function is looking for the index based on the value. In your first array there are elements with the value `3` and `1`, but the second is an array of objects, so clearly it will not correct find them. Instead simply use the direct index given. Use the values of `max,min` as the index themselves. Note that the index goes from `0 .. n-1` rather than `1 .. n`. So then `range(3,1)` would be `range(2,0)` (*if you want to use it as `range(3,1)` just subtract 1 from the values inside the function*):

```
function range(min, max) {
    var startArr = max >= min ? arr.slice(min, max + 1) : arr.slice(min),
        endArr = max < min ? arr.slice(0, max + 1) : [];
    return startArr.concat(endArr);
}
...
range(2, 0);
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgvjaghz/3/)

Comment: Thank you. But why it not works in case  `range(0, 3)`, means when `min < max`

Comment: It's because of the condition `max < arr.length `, change it to `max < min`. Basically what happens is the value of `startArr` basically gets the entire array, and `endArr` gets the entire array.

Comment: Another thing that in this case it don't slice `max`, so the result looks `[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Mark"},{"id":3,"name":"Jim"},{"id":4,"name":"Bob"}]` instead `[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Mark"},{"id":3,"name":"Jim"}]`

Comment: @SamuelK Ah, looks like `arr.slice(min)` or `arr.slice(min, max + 1)` should be done for `startArr` depending on which value is larger than which. I've updated my solution, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! Don't sorry. I'm JS idiot and all this are helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the 'lodash' javascript library https://lodash.com/

For an **'array'**

Sounds like you are after either

1. Slice - http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#slice
2. TakeWhile